Mapping custom root domain to Windows Azure CDN does not work
I added the custom domain www.contoso.com to my cdn but when I try to add contoso.com it says:

We couldn't find a DNS record for 'contoso.com' that points to 'cdn-name.azureedge.net'. Before you can associate a domain with this CDN endpoint, you need to create a CNAME record with your DNS provider for 'contoso.com' that points to 'cdn-name.azureedge.net'.

The only answers I find on this are using the Azure dns, I am not. My dns provider is porkbun and I added an alias pointing to the cdn, yet I'm still getting this issue. Is there a step that I am missing or is it just not possible?

The error occurs because Azure CDN requires a valid CNAME record pointing your domain (e.g., contoso.com) to the CDN endpoint (cdn-name.azureedge.net) before allowing you to associate the domain. However, contoso.com (apex or root domain) cannot directly have a CNAME record due to DNS restrictions. Root domains cannot use CNAME records but can use ALIAS/ANAME.

Yes, I have an alias record, host: contoso.com, answer: cdn-name.azureedge.net, yet the problem persists.
